# Generating Enums with ng-swagger-gen

Tags: angular, enums, swagger, swagger-codegen

I want to generate models in Angular application from SpringBoot Rest services and for this purpose I use ng-swagger-gen plugin. But somehow, the Enums are generated only as **inline String** values and not the Enum class so everytime I must either type string value or create the Enum object in Typescript by myself.

```
@Data
public class DummyClass {
   private DummyEnum dummyEnum;
}

public enum DummyEnum {
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

And only 1 file representaing the model is generated:

```
export interface DummyClass {
dummyEnum?: 'One' | 'Two' | 'Three';
}
```

The swagger definition looks like this:

```
"definitions": {
"DummyClass": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "dummyEnum": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three"
      ]
    }
  },
  "title": "DummyClass"
 }
}
```

Instead when I **manually** change the definition to this, everything looks OK, there are 2 files generated, 1 class and 1 enum

```
"definitions": {
"DummyClass": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "dummyEnum": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/DummyEnum"
    }
  }
},
"DummyEnum": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three"
  ]
}
}
```

And in Typescript:

```
import { DummyEnum } from './dummy-enum';
  export interface DummyClass {
 dummyEnum?: DummyEnum;
  }
```

Could you please advice whats the correct approach? I desperately needs the enum classes in my Angular Application, but I want to them to be **generated** and not created manually. Seems like ng-swagger-gen plugin is working correctly but somehow Springfox Swagger2 considered Enums as second class object and therefore not included them into the definitions part.

Thanks